# Displaying a web page in Android using Qt for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I've heard that **QtWebKit** is not available in **Android**. But now I'm developing an application for **Android** using **Qt/QtQuick2** and I need to let users login to their Instagram profiles through my application.
And this needs to display a web page from Instagram to users.(There isn't second way)
Is this possible to display a webpage in Android using **Qt 5.3.1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt WebEngine Technology is under development. For a Qt and cross platform solution you should wait for it to be available on Android.

Currently to incorporate web content into your Qt application on Android, you need to use a native web component. Interacting with native contents could be done by the [Qt Android Extras](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) module with a JNI convenience API.